# Heap Memory Issue on Centos

Tags: java, linux, heap-memory, centos6

What is the command to check allocate heap memory? and how can I increase memory allocated to java.

My Environment conf are this:

1. centos 6.8
2. Apache tomcat 8.5.38
3. jdk version 1.8.0

I have already tried these

1. CMD To check heap memory
   `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize`

Result
[image]

3. CMD To Increase Heap memory
   `java -Xmx8000m -XshowSettings:all`

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the contents of the heap and its total size by using the [appropriate tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-objects-in-the-jvm-heap.html) in Intellij.

If you want to increase it, there are some caveats, but overall its explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java). You are using the right command, overall.

What exactly do you want to achieve ? How will you measure success ?